# PHP/Wordpress comparing post date to current date - posts expiring too early

Tags: wordpress

This is what I currently use to display posts for upcoming club events:

```
<?php


    $query = new WP_Query( array(

        'post_type' => 'event',
        'nopaging' => 'true',
        'meta_key'   => 'event_date',
        'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'meta_value'    => date('Ymd'),
        'meta_compare'  => '>=',
        'date_query'    => array(
            array(
                    'key' => 'date',
                    'value' => date('Ymd'),
                    'compare' => '>=', //Greater than or equal to
                    'type' => 'DATETIME'
                )
            ),

        ) );

    ?>
```

Generally, this works. Events that are upcoming are displayed, and events that have passed are not. However, I have run into an issue with evening events. My events are not displaying as soon as the EVENING of the day of the event. They should not be disappearing until the NEXT day. If possible, I'd like to even overshoot a bit and have events display for 1 day AFTER the event as well.

I've checked the time zone of my Wordpress site- it is set to Vancouver (we are in Seattle), so that is correct.

Any ideas on how I can tweak my code so that my events don't expire too early? I haven't found anyone use the format I've used above, so I'm feeling stuck.

Comment: You are using date() function of php native so you may check your server's timezone also... Are in your php file, before using date, you can set the timezone to your desired like: 
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Yes, I pasted this at the top of my functions.php file:
`date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`

and that did the trick! Thank you!